# Assigning returned objects and copy constructor and destructor calls

Tags: c++11, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

So I am trying to experiment with some code to see if I understand copy constructor calls and destructor calls when passing values to functions. However, I'm confused:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(int a)
    {
        std::cout<<"Constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test& copy)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy constructor called"<<std::endl;
        this->a = copy.a;
    }

    Test& operator=(const Test& copy)
    {
        this->a = copy.a;
        std::cout<<"Copy assignment operator called"<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    //Test& operator=(Test&& move) = delete;
    //Test(Test&& move) = delete;
    /*Test& operator=(Test&& move)
    {
        this->a = move.a;
        std::cout<<"Move assignment operator called"<<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }*/
    /*Test(Test&& move)
    {
        this->a = move.a;
        std::cout<<"Move constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }*/
    //invoked when passing 1...

    int a;
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destructor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};

Test function(Test a_test)
{
    std::cout<<"In 'function'"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Returning"<<std::endl;
    return a_test;//copy constructor called to assign to temporary value that is being returned, and then destructor for a_test is called
}

int main()
{
    Test test1 = function(1);//copy constructor called again, and then destructor for temp value is called?
    std::cout<<"DONE WITH THIS ROUND"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    test1 = function(1);//??
    std::cout<<"DONE WITH THIS ROUND"<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the first line in main is doing?

To explain my confusion, from what I understand, main should call the function while passing the integer 1. Since Test 'a_test' is a parameter for the function, and it can take an integer for construction, it is constructed with the integer passed in as 1. Then we return 'a_test', in which case a copy constructor should be invoked to copy the contents of 'a_test' into the contents of the "return value". Then, the destructor should be called to delete the contents in 'a_test'. Then, the copy constructor should be invoked for 'test1', to copy the contents of the "return value". Then, after we are done copying the contents, the destructor should be called for the "return value".

However, I get the following output:

```
Constructor called
In 'function'
Returning
Copy constructor called
Destructor called
DONE WITH THIS ROUND

Constructor called
In 'function'
Returning
Copy constructor called
Copy assignment operator called
Destructor called
Destructor called
DONE WITH THIS ROUND

Destructor called
```

So it seems I have the wrong idea and feel totally confused.
I expected:

```
Constructor called
In 'function'
Returning
Copy constructor called
Destructor called
Copy constructor called
Destructor called
DONE WITH THIS ROUND

....
```

And then the rest of the output, that I think I could understand if I can understand the first line of main first.

Comment: I believe you're observing [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The compiler is allowed to omit certain unnecessary copies.

Comment: As Fred Larson said, you are indeed observing copy elision and return value optimization. Check this link: http://blog.knatten.org/2011/08/26/dont-be-afraid-of-returning-by-value-know-the-return-value-optimization/